# Is cURL in PHP tied to the local install of cURL?

Tags: php, windows, curl

IE, does PHP use its own, internal version of cURL or does it use whatever it finds in the local OS (Windows 10)? I'm in the unfortunate position of trying to make scripts written in 7.4 work on a permanent home that's saddled with 7.1. Before I force an update of PHP, I want to make sure chasing the right problem. I've searched php.ini and don't see a path to the local file system.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it is an extension. https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

Comment: My only reccomendation is to use https://www.docker.com/ to create an environment that replicates your webserver, that way you are not bound to testing under windows, but deploying on something else, its a bit of work to get started, but its very useful for this kind of situation if you have to compare multiple versions of PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curl functions in PHP do not call out to a *command-line* version of curl, but rather to a *library* which can be integrated into a C program.

This version may be included "statically" when PHP is compiled, be a separate file installed alongside PHP, or use a shared file installed centrally on the server and used by multiple programs. This will be determined by the distribution package of PHP.

To determine the library version used, use the [`phpinfo()`](https://php.net/phpinfo) function, or run `php -i` on the command line (which just runs that function for you) and search for "curl", which will show the version.

Comment: Thanks, php -i will be very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is.
IE is not an issue here.
I always keep a script that gives me the current state of PHP.
[PHP Manual, phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

```
<?php
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

**phpinfo will return something like this if curl is (likely) installed.**

[image: PHP infoinfo() curl]

Comment: IE, in this context, stands for Ibid Est or "in other words". I'm a little old school and not a windows person, so I missed the confusion there :). This is PHP scripting, so php_info() wouldn't work, or  I'm not sure how to easily make it work for me for diagnostic purposes. after getting permission to upgrade to 8.1 and getting curl working through it on my dev device, I found that PHP does install its own curl executable as an extension.

The fear was I'd "harass" people to get PHP upgraded and then turn around and have it not solve the issue because php called to the OS curl.exe

Comment: Oh i.e.  I showed the PHP Info so you can see which curl version, if any, is installed.  The image is from the phpinfo() results.

Answer (score 0):

I learned through the process of installing PHP 8.1 in my dev env and configuring it to use curl (and a comment), that PHP does call it's own curl executable, in the case of windows 10: php_curl.dll, and does not make an external call to curl in the operating system.

My fear was I'd go through the process of getting someone to upgrade PHP then have to have ask, again, to have curl upgraded.

Thanks to all who offered input!

Comment: There are a couple of misconceptions here: Firstly, a DLL is not the same thing as an executable; it's a piece of code that will be *included dynamically into the PHP executable*. Secondly, PHP can be installed in many different ways; the fact that *the particular installer you used* includes a copy of curl in no way guarantees that the PHP installed on some other system also has its own copy, rather than sharing one with other packages installed on the same system.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I take it that'd be specified in the ini file? I like to have the complete story squirreled away so I can almost remember it for future debugging :)

Comment: I think it would be part of the options passed when PHP is compiled, rather than in the ini file.

Answer (score 0):

yes, but curl is an extension, you need to enable it in php.ini file